# How to fetch limited amount of users from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I am doing a card stack swipe app with users similar to `Tinder`.

I want to fetch a batch of 10 users from `Firebase`. I have used `queryLimited(toFirst: 10)` for this but later in my function i won't fetch the users who have already been accepted(swiped right). This means that if the first 10 users from `Firebase` already have been accepted nobody will be fetched. I want to fetch the first 10 users who hasn't been accepted.

Does anyone have a great solution for this?

Thank you.

`FetchUsers` code for fetching users from `Firebase`:

```
func fetchAllUsers(completion: @escaping (_ message: String) -> Void){
    //User or advertiser?
    Database.database().reference(withPath: "Advertiser").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists(){
            myAdvertiserVar.advertiser = true
            self.currentUserKind = "Advertiser"
            self.otherUserKind = "Users"
        }
        else{
            myAdvertiserVar.advertiser = false
            self.currentUserKind = "Users"
            self.otherUserKind = "Advertiser"
        }

        // Fetch
        let query = self.ref?.child(self.otherUserKind).queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryLimited(toFirst: 10)
        query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
            (snapshot) in

            let g = DispatchGroup()

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let id = child.key

                //If Already Accepted, don't fetch
                g.enter()

                Database.database().reference(withPath: self.currentUserKind).child(self.uid).child("Accepted").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(accepted) in
                    if accepted.exists(){
                        print("\(id) är redan Accepted")
                    }
                    else{
                        if myAdvertiserVar.advertiser == true{
                            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                            let username = value?["Username"] as? String
                            let occupation = value?["Occupation"] as? String
                            let age = value?["Age"] as? String
                            let bio = value?["Bio"] as? String
                            let email = value?["email"] as? String
                            let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                            self.usersArray.append(user)
                        }
                        else{
                            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                            let username = value?["Owner"] as? String
                            let occupation = value?["Location"] as? String
                            let age = value?["Rent"] as? String
                            let bio = value?["About"] as? String
                            let email = value?["email"] as? String
                            let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                            self.usersArray.append(user)
                        }
                    }

                    g.leave()
                })
            }


            g.notify(queue: .main, execute: {

                print(self.usersArray.count)
                completion("Users list fetched")

            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: There are three observers in your code, but none of them limits the number of children it returns. Please make sure that your question contains the minimal, complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated now with ".queryLimited(toFirst: 10)" under the comment //Fetch

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. So you can either get the 10 users ordered by their email address, *or* 10 that have a specific value for the property. In many cases it may be possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So in your case something like `"status_email": "accepted_olle@company.com"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase